# looking for code able to pause the JavaScript and only activate it when onclick else don't do anything

Tags: javascript, asp.net, confirm

I am looking for simple JavaScript for okay/cancel function. just like Hotmail when want to delete email, it will prompt you whether you wan to proceed or cancel.

My current code will just auto runs two JavaScript.
So now I am looking for code that will pause the JavaScript and only activate it when onclick else don't do anything.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var first = confirm("We are sending you to an external site, do you wish to proceed? ")
        if (first)
            window.location = "http://www.google.com"
           
        else
            window.close;


        var second = confirm("We are sending you to an external site, do you wish to proceed? ")
        if (second)
            window.location = "http://www.yahoo.com"

        else
            window.close;
    </script>

<a href="" onclick="javascript:first" title="opens the external website in a new window">Google</a>

<a href="" onclick="javascript:second" title="opens the external website in a new window">Yahoo</a>
```

Comment: You never need `javascript:` in an `onclick` attribute. You do need to wrap your code in *functions* in order to refer to them in an `onclick` attribute. So `function first() { if (confirm(...))) { window.location = ...; } else { window.close(); } }`

Comment: You may want to take some introductory tutorials in JavaScript; I suggest MDN's [introduction to JavaScript functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Functions).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
window.close()
```

To make something run on click, use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener), or a wrapper around that.